# Xdebug / Vim / getting it to work

Tags: php, vim, xdebug

So I have tried following multiple tutorials to get xdebug to work on my development server. The best one I have found so far is [this](https://mutelight.org/minimal-guide-to-debugging-php-with-xdebug-and-vim).

I have installed xdebug and it shows correctly in my phpinfo(). I have installed https://github.com/joonty/vdebug and when I hit F5 it works great. The problem is I then go to my dev server ip address like so "http:///?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1" and it doesn't trip anything. My vim xdebug just times out.

I have set up my php.ini file the following way:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have these settings in my debug.ini

```
0 zend_extension=xdebug.so                                                                                            
1 xdebug.remote_enable=on
2 xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
3 xdebug.remote_host=localhost
4 xdebug.remote_port=9000
5 
6 xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
7 xdebug.profiler_append=0
8 xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=On
9 xdebug.profiler_output_name="%H-%u.trace"
10 
11 xdebug.profiler_enable=0
12 xdebug.remote_autostart=1
13 xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
```

The profiler stuff is non-relevant, but remote_autostart might help you.

Comment: I added that in except i kept my `zend_extension=` since mine is in a different directory and still the same issue. Can't seem to kick off the debug session

Comment: Have you enabled the xdebug mod (OS dependant I guess)? Is the .so file readable by the web-server user (OS dependant)? Does xdebug show on phpinfo as loading correctly? Maybe you should take a step back from vim/vdebug and make sure xdebug is running first.

Comment: This answer actually worked. I forgot to reset my apache server but once I did it worked. I am thinking that it was actually the remote_handler=dbgp setting but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Of course - I forgot the classic 'did you restart apache' ;-)